# Knowing if equations can be inconsistent by looking at null space

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I know that inconsistency is detected by looking at the rref of the augmented matrix, but let's say that i have the rref of the coefficient matrix.

AKA I have the coefficients of the variables, but none of the constants.

(or alternately, i have the kernel or null space, if that's easier)

How would I go about knowing whether inconsistency was possible or not in that system of equations?

I can reason about simple examples but is there a formal way to see whether inconsistency is possible, or details of how inconsistency could be made?

Some examples I can reason about below.

These equations can't be inconsistent:

$x+y=A\\
y=B\\
A,B \in \mathbb{R}
$

They have this coefficient matrix in rref:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

These can be inconsistent, but aren't necessarily:

$x+y=A\\
x=B\\
y=C \\
A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}
$

And here is the coefficients matrix in rref for those:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Let's say you have a nonhomogeneous system of two equations in two variables and I tell you that the rref form of the system is

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

From this information you can deduce that the original system doesn't have a unique solution for each $(A,B)$ you put in the right hand side and when there are solutions, there will be infinitely many but you cannot tell for a specific $(A,B)$ (say $(1,2)$) whether the system will have a solution.

To see an example, consider the systems $x = A, 0 = B$ and $x = A, x = B$. The rref of the coefficient matrices

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

is the same but the first system can be solved for $(1,0)$ while the second cannot be solved for $(1,0)$.

Comment: I think that I need to ask a new question then, but am unsure if this is the right question.  Would it be appropriate for me to ask "Is it possible to know if a system of equations can be made to be inconsistent if you are able to change the constants on the right side of the equations?"

Comment: @AlanWolfe: If you are asking "Can I determined whether for some choice of the right hand side the system won't have any solutions" then the answer is yes. If the rref matrix $A$ is $n \times m$, you need to check whether $\operatorname{rank}(A) < n$. If this happens, you can make the system inconsistent, if it doesn't then you can't.